# php validation and mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm making a registration form using PHP and mongodb. This form works but the problem is it's not carrying out the validations. Even if I leave all the fields empty, it updates the database with the empty fields. Its as if the whole `error = array();` is invisible.

What I need is for it to perform the checks and not update the database until all the requirements are met.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if($_POST['submit']){
        $ScName=strip_tags($_POST['ScName']);
        $fname=strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
        $lname=strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
        $email=strip_tags($_POST['email']);
        $password=strip_tags($_POST['password']);
        $password2=strip_tags($_POST['password2']);

        $error = array();

            if(empty($email) or !filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)){
              $error[] = "Email id is empty or invalid";
            }
            if(empty($password)){
              $error[] = "Please enter password";
            }
            if(empty($password2)){
              $error[] = "Please Confirm password";
            }
            if($password != $password2){
               $error[] = "Password and Confirm password are not matching";
            }
            if(empty($fname)){
                $error[] = "Enter first name";
            }
            if(empty($lname)){
                $error[] = "Enter last name";
            }

            if(count($error == 0)){
                //database configuration
                $host = 'localhost';
                $database_name = 'mongo1';
                $database_user_name = '';  
                $database_password = '';  

                 $connection=new Mongo('localhost');

                 if($connection){

                     //connecting to database
                     $database=$connection->user;

                     //connect to specific collection
                     $collection=$database->user;

                     $query=array('email'=>$email);
                     //check for existing username
                     //$query=array('ScName'=>$ScName);
                     //checking for existing user
                     $count=$collection->findOne($query);

                     if(!count($count)){
                         //Save the New user
                         $user=array('fname'=>$fname,'lname'=>$lname,'ScName'=>$ScName,'email'=>$email,'password'=>md5($password));             
                         $collection->save($user);
                         echo "You are successfully registered.";
                     }else{
                         echo "Email already exists.Please register with another Email";
                     }

                 }else{

                      die("Database is not connected");
                 }

            }else{
                //Displaying the error
                foreach($error as $err){
                    echo $err.'</br>';
                }
            }
            }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misplaced the bracket at

```
if(count($error == 0)){
```

Since `$error == 0` is `false`, as `$error` is a populated array, `count(false)` evaluates as `0` (i.e., `false`), and the `if` branch doesn't execute. You should close the bracket after `$error`:

```
if (count($error) == 0) {
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works now. i was at it for hours and couldnt figure it out